# jQuery datepicker: highlight and style multiple dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm using the jQuery date picker as an online calendar too. I have a setup which takes the date values in the `data-value` attribute of the `.whats-on-block` divs, and assigns the `.special` class to the relevant date value in the jQuery date picker, thus I can style it accordingly via CSS.
This works great, I also have a `.highlights` div with multiple date values as the `data-highlight` attribute, I'm wondering if I can assign the `.highlighter` class to the relevant date values in the date picker so I can style these separately? I'm not really sure how to achieve this as the `beforeShowDay` function is already being used to assign the `.special`. Here's the markup...
HTML

```
<div class="whats-on-grid">
    <div class="datepicker-block" class="whats-on-block">
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="whats-on-block" data-value="1982014"></div>
    <div class="whats-on-block" data-value="2282014"></div>
    <div class="whats-on-block" data-value="1482014"></div>
    <div class="whats-on-block" data-value="2982014"></div>
    //etc
</div>


<div class="highlights" data-highlight="2882014 2782014 1582014 2082014 1992014"></div>
```

CSS

```
.special { background-color: red !important; }
.highlighter { background-color: blue !important; }
```

jQuery

```
var $container = $('.whats-on-grid');
var $blocks = $("div.whats-on-block", ".whats-on-grid");

$(function () {
    var blocks = $('.whats-on-grid .whats-on-block')
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        //nextText: '&rarr;',
        //prevText: '&larr;',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        //dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        dayNamesMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
        //showOn: "button",
        //buttonImage: "img/calendar-blue.png",
        //buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = new Date(dateText);
            var dateValue = date.getDate().toString() + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getFullYear().toString();

            $container.isotope({
                filter: '[data-value~="' + dateValue + '"], #datepicker-block'
            });
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var target = date.getDate().toString() + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getFullYear().toString();
            var contains = blocks.filter('[data-value~="' + target + '"]').length > 0;
            return [true, contains ? 'special' : '', '']
        }
    });
});
```

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your problem?

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to add the `highlighter` class to the `highlights` dates in the `beforeShowDay` function?

Comment: @isim yes I am trying to add the `highlighter` class to the relevant dates in the datepicker references in the `data-highlight` attribute. Thus these dates in the `#datepicker` will have a blue background as per the CSS.

Comment: @user1374796 if the answer provided is helpful and correct, please accept. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is to add the `highlighter` class to the `highlights` dates prior to rendering, you should be able to easily achieved that in your `beforeShowDay` function like this:

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var target = date.getDate().toString() + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getFullYear().toString();
    var isSpecial = blocks.filter('[data-value~="' + target + '"]').length > 0;
    var isHighlight = $("div[class~='highlights']").filter('[data-highlight~="' + target + '"]').length > 0;
    if (isSpecial) 
        return [true, 'special', ''];
    else if (isHighlight)
        return [true, 'highlighter', ''];
    return [true, '', ''];
    }
```

The tricky part is what if a special date is also a highlight date. You may need different CSS styling to distinguish them.

Live demo available on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/axfv2eo1/).